# Issue exporting war with eclipse for weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: eclipse, weblogic

I am using eclipse to build a web app to be deployed on weblogic 10.3.6.Performing a export as war and depolying the war on weblogic fails at a point where I am performing a file move opertation using java.nio.file.Files.move method. 
The error I receive is following :-

`java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /export/home/tppp3/asdsslon/infiles/Wert_Frameon_20160514.csv
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:403)`

However this is not reported when I perform a deployment to weblogic using eclipse available option Run as-> Run on Server . 
I am noticing Using above method, generates a _wl_cls_gen.jar with source code files compiled and package as class.

Any help will be appreciated. 
I am looking for option to either generate _wl_cls_gen.jar for war export or find a option to make the move operation work. The same war works flawlessly on Tomcat.

Thanks